# ACRA Not sending information

Tags: android, couchdb, acra

```
@ReportsCrashes(
        formKey = "",
        formUri = "https://blabla.cloudant.com/acra-blabla/_design/acra-storage/_update/report",
        reportType = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON,
        httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT,
        formUriBasicAuthLogin="lymentanduransimedgednem",
        formUriBasicAuthPassword="bcLI3RWTrCtvOTy2caet4HVD",
        // Your usual ACRA configuration
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
        forceCloseDialogAfterToast = false, // optional, default false
        resToastText = R.string.app_id


        )

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ACRA.init(this);
    registerImageLoader();
    registerNetworkListener();


}
```

This is in my application class

```
public class App extends Application {
```

I expect my app to send a toast and data to my acralyzer link that ive set up. But nothing happens! I just get a regular stopped working and than my app shuts off

I am using Protokit/HoloEverywhere i dont know if that matters or not?

Comment: what service are you using for Acra? I.E Bugsense ...

Comment: Did u added app to manifest file ?    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/site_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:name="App ">

Comment: Also make sure ur app has permission to access network..